# How to use Lucene with SQLite Database?

Tags: database, sqlite, lucene, full-text-search

How can i use Lucene to index my SQLite Database for Full-Text Search ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Hibernate-Lucene bridge](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-2008/jw-07-hibernate-search.html), but this will require you to use Hibernate.

Comment: :Thanks but i am not using Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

Lucene is "nothing more" than java libraries. That means, you have to use those libraries "with something".

One way is the Hibernate-Lucene bridge, as mindas wrote.

An other way (which I'm using) is solr.

You can use solr to index your SQLite Database. 
But: you have to send the (full-text-)search-request to solr to run such a search. As far as i know, there is nor lucene integration for SQLite Databases.
You will need an proxy (like solr) and an application, which merges the world of SQLite and solr (or an other lucene "proxy") together.